# Dollars render as (Slash + Dollar) in firefox that uses Mathjax

Tags: bug, mathjax

I'm using [Mathjax](https://mathjax.org/) offline and all equations and expressions are rendered perfectly but the dollar symbol renders as given in the title(can't write it here).Is there anyway to render it as the dollar symbol($)?

For example dollar 6000 is rendered as $\1600

Comment: Can you clarify if you're using mathjax on this website or elsewhere? Because if you're using it elsewhere, then you should ask your question elsewhere... This isn't a general mathjax support site.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/403/texification-is-too-aggressive-or-how-to-enter-a-dollar-sign

Comment: @NajibIdrissi:Yeah that's very right.I'll ask it at a mathjax support site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you escape your dollar sign: `$\$$` gives $\$$.

I.e. inside a math environment: `$\$ 6000$` gives $\$ 6000$. In plain text, just use `\$6000` to get \$6000.

Comment: :I would like to know if we could get dollar 6000 as dollar 6000 instead of /$6000 that I get now in html web page.

Comment: This answer shows you how to get \$6000 in plain text and $\$6000$ in MathJax. What exactly are you trying to do?