# Backslash-dollar in "code" format renders with two backslashes

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

"Code" formatted text in Markdown is indicated inline by putting the text between backquotes, or by indenting the text at least four spaces.

In the two examples below, I have typed a **single** backslash followed by a dollar sign, but Stack Exchange's edit preview rendered **two** backslashes followed by a dollar sign:

Here is inline **single** backslash followed by dollar sign: `\\\$`

```
    Here is display **single** backslash followed by dollar sign: `\\\$`
```

After I save the article, SE renders the text with **three** backslashes before each dollar sign.

I think a single backslash followed by a dollar sign should render as a single backslash followed by a dollar sign, not as two or three backslashes followed by a dollar sign.

### Screenshots

#### As written with **single** backslashes

> [image: As written with single backslashes]

#### As rendered (in preview) with **two** backslashes

> [image: As rendered with two backslashes]

#### As rendered (finally) with **three** backslashes

> [image: As rendered with three backslashes]

---

I am using Firefox 83.0 (64-bit) for Ubuntu.

[This earlier question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22370/dollars-render-as-slash-dollar-in-firefox-that-uses-mathjax) may be reporting the same thing but the description is unclear.

Comment: A recent post on [meta.se]: [Rendering bug with backslash and dollar sign on MathJax-enabled sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357702).