# Inconsistency between markdown in comments and posts

Tags: bug, comment, markdown

There is an inconsistency between the Markdown for codeblocks in comments and the Markdown in Questions and Answers: it seems to me impossible  to type  `\` (as in, literally a backslash in a codeblock alone) in a comment. I think this is in contradiction with [the spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/) of CommonMark which [SE now implements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark).

I discovered this about the same time I rediscovered [with](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34574/how-to-write-in-mathjax#comment161030_34574) TheAmplitwist an [already reported bug on \\$ in codeblocks](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32856/backslash-dollar-in-code-format-renders-with-two-backslashes?noredirect=1&lq=1) that makes item 15 in the Question body of [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) display wrongly.<sup>1</sup>

[A long time ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/16/new-improved-comments-with-reply/), comments were set to use a restricted version of Markdown; I guess this has not been updated, because **one cannot reproduce the \\$ bug in the comments.** The combination of the two bugs made discussing them a little confusing.

As the \\$ bug is Mathjax-related, I am posting here instead of meta.SE (first?) in case this bug is also Mathjax related. (I don't know if I can post `test' comments on meta.SE.)

I'll post a comment below to illustrate the bug with the input: [image] . For comparison, the result in a Question is: `\&\\\$\#\_\{\}\`[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KunP.png). Note the reproduction of the \\$ bug.

---

<sup>1</sup> Given that the optimal solution (\\$ bug fix) hasn't come. I think its better to have the correct instruction displayed in the Mathjax tutorial (`\&`\\$`\#\_\{\}`) instead of what "should be" correct (`\&\\\$\#\_\{\}`), but perhaps this should be discussed in a separate math.meta post.

Comment: And here with the same input: `\&\$\#\_\{\}\`. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKUGu.png)

Comment: This seems right. Mathjax and markdown have confusing compatibility problems, and I can imagine this would be a surprisingly annoying thing to try to work out.

Comment: You can type them in comments, but they can be difficult. I think sufficient spaces after them renders them visible: `\  &$\   #_` with two spaces after each backslash. And `\ $#\ ` with one space. A space before the final quote mark works: `\$#\ ` but without the space it seems to interpret the backslash as an escape character for the backquote: `\$#\` and does not leave the mode until another \` `.

Comment: I think the problem is that final `\\` ` which gets interpreted as an escape character. Add a space between the backslash and the quote mark and it seems to work.

Comment: Indeed. Also note that your comment does not display `\\\$` when you typed `\$`, ie the \$ bug does not repro in comments (hence ‘inconsistency’ in title)